# PHP Login form redirect to blank php page

Tags: php, mysql

I recently just completed a User Registration with PHP/MySQL which adds new users to a DB. I now have a Login form that should allow these users to login.
The HTML form is simple:

```
<form method="POST" action="login.php">
            <p><input type="text" name="login" value="" placeholder="Username"></p>
            <p><input type="password" name="password" value="" placeholder="Password"></p>

            <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Login</button>

       </form>
```

And the PHP it directs to is - using this tutorial ([here](http://mrbool.com/how-to-create-a-login-page-with-php-and-mysql/28656)):

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'password');
if (!$connection){
     die("Database Connection Failed" . mysql_error());
}

$select_db = mysql_select_db('gmaps1');
if (!$select_db){
    die("Database Selection Failed" . mysql_error());
}

function LogIn()
{
    session_start();
    if(!empty($_POST['username']))
    {

        // Check if these values exist in the DB
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username =    '$_POST[username]' AND password = '$_POST[password]'") or die(mysql_error());

    $row = mysql_fetch_array($query);

    if(!empty($row['username']) AND !empty($row['password']))
    {
        $_SESSION['username'] = $row['password'];
        echo "SUCCESSFUL LOGIN";
    }

    else
    {
        // If no match - Error is displayed
        echo "SORRY. WRONG DETAILS";
        //echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Invalid Login Details');</script>";
    }
}
}

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    LogIn();
}

?>
```

The problem is when the form is submitted, it redirects to a blank "login.php" page, displaying no text or errors. This happens when the form is filled out, left blank or with details not matching saved users.

Comment: Lovely [sql injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com) vulnerability you have there. Enjoy having your server pwn3d.

Comment: Its only for a College project and will solely be used on a localserver so its not a big deal for now anyways

Comment: wrong attitude. "simple projects" have a habit of persisting long past their expected "use by" date, and for all you know, the prof might give you bonus points for writing secure code. I would, if I were teaching this sort of thing.

Comment: Returns "Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in/......./ on Line 46"

Comment: @ Narendra: It's not a method in a class.

Comment: You don't have a form element bearing the `username` name attribute; you have `name="login"`. Plus, where's your code to support `Using $this when not in object context in...`?

Comment: hey @MarcB calm down, there is a world outside, people are different, theoretically we are here to help no to complain

Comment: Watch somebody sink their teeth into my comment and post an answer.

Comment: Your error checking... should have trigged an undefined index username.

Comment: I decided NOT to post my comment as an answer, because I don't know where the code related to `Using $this when not in object context in...` is used.

Comment: @FrancescoE. I just posted another comment to that effect, just above yours.

Comment: That tutorial btw, should either be updated or deleted; **it's totally unsafe**. You should be using prepared statements and `password_hash()`. Here, see this instead  https://daveismyname.com/login-and-registration-system-with-php-bp#.VJwyRc3AHA

Answer (score 0):

Yes Fred, the problem was there was no name "username". so I changed this line:

```
<p><input type="text" name="login" value="" placeholder="Username"></p>
```

To this:

```
<p><input type="text" name="username" value="" placeholder="Username"></p>
```

Comment: [Read this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29281195/php-login-form-redirect-to-blank-php-page#comment46760908_29281195) which is why I didn't post an answer because of just that. It was an unknown.

Answer (score -1):

You haven't indicated what you've called your files.

Your form's action is "login.php". That means that it will look for a file called "login.php" in the docroot. If that file doesn't exist, then you'll get a "file not found" error. So "the PHP that it redirects to" should be saved in a file called "login.php" which must be in the same folder as your form. Then you should set the form action="/login.php", which will look for the php file in the same folder as the form – this may save you some headaches if your form is not in your domain's docroot.

You shouldn't be seeing a blank page because your web server won't serve a blank page by default for a missing file. So if you're seeing a blank page, chances are that PHP is generating errors but not displaying them. Find out where your PHP log files are kept and check those. Also check your php.ini file (for log file paths, for loggin status and error reporting in general).

Also whatever is being shown in the URL should give you a clue to where the browser is looking – so check that location in your file-system and see what it's pointing at. If there's an empty "login.php" file at that location then your form's action is pointing at the wrong "login.php" file.

Also your PHP is looking for a posted key of "username" but your form does not contain that key. In your form you are using "login" instead of "username". Your PHP logic does not do anything if "username" is not received... so it will be blank.